# How should I fix list index out of range error while inputting a list into google sheets?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, google-sheets, gspread

I keep getting this error no matter what I change with the range, I was just wondering if anyone could explain what I have to do to fix this. Listed below is the code where I get the error. Any help is appreciated.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4
import re
import time

memberList = []

res = requests.get('https://plancke.io/hypixel/guild/name/GBP')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

for i in soup.select('.playerInfo'):
    memberList.append(i.text)

memberList = [e[37:-38] for e in memberList]
members = [re.sub("[A-Z][^A-Z]+$", "", member.split(" ")[1]) for member in memberList]

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('GBP Google Sheets').sheet1

data = sheet.get_all_records()

memberCol = sheet.col_values(16)
memberCol.pop(0)
memberCol.pop(0)
memberCol.pop(0)
memberCol.pop(0)
memberCol.pop(0)
memberCol.pop(0)
memberCol.pop(0)
memberCol.pop(0)
memberCol.pop(0)
memberCol.pop(0)
memberCol.pop(0)
memberCol.pop(0)

for i in range(len(memberCol) + 2):
    time.sleep(1.2)
    sheet.update_cell(i + 12,16, members[i - 1])
```

If there is an easier way to input a list into google sheets that would also be appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: First of all the range at the last loop starts at 0, so i-1 will give index -1 at the begning, which is out of bounds. Also check that the last number in the range minus 1 is still inside the range of the members array.

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused, I had the i-1 to make sure that I got the first element in the list, but now I don't get the first element and I still have an error.
```
for i in range(len(memberCol) + 1):
    time.sleep(1.2)
    sheet.update_cell(i + 12,16, members[i])
```
I'm still unsure of what I should exactly do to remove the error.

Comment: Check if len(memberCol) + 2 is bigger then the size of members

Comment: Basically, if the size of memberCol is 5, then the loop will go from 0 up to 5 + whatever number you decide, in the case of what you posted, 5+2, so from 0 up to 6. If the members array is of size 5, then you will get an index out of bounds when it tries to access the last item as it doesnt exist.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

By having a quick look and without knowing in which line this exception is raised I can only guess its due to the first call on the for loop at the end of the code.

The range function in python will return you with the numbers from 0 up, therefore at your loop:

```
for i in range(len(memberCol) + 2):
time.sleep(1.2)
sheet.update_cell(i + 12,16, members[i - 1])
```

You will find that the first time the loop is ran, with the i value of 0, the index that you are trying to access from members will be members[0-1], -1 being out of the index.

Apart from that, depending on the length of memberCol, you might get again the index out of bounds as the size of memberCol + 2 might exceed the number of members in the array, raising again the exception.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me understand what I was doing wrong!

Comment: You are welcome. If you found this to be an appropiate solution mark it by clicking the tick mark next to the upvote/downvote buttons for others to see it easier.